# Is it possible to have a "professional" take a look at my whole HTML / CSS Project here?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Is it possible to upload an entire HTML/CSS code project on this site for review, rather than just a small code snippet?

I'm currently working on a r/place clone and while my code works fine, it would be interesting to see if someone has better approaches or coding methods to potentially improve it.

Alternatively, is there another platform where I can share a whole project and receive feedback?

Or is it possible to connect with someone privately to discuss about it further?

Code example:

```
function drawInitialCanvas(canvasData) {
  const imageData = new ImageData(newCanvasWidth, newCanvasHeight);
  const data = new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.data.buffer);
  for (let y = 0; y < newCanvasHeight; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < newCanvasWidth; x++) {
      const colorObj = canvasData[y][x]; // Zugriff auf das Objekt bei [y][x]
      const color = colorObj.color; // Zugriff auf die Farbeigenschaft des Objekts
      const rgbValues = color.match(/\d+/g);
      const index = (y * newCanvasWidth + x) * 4;
      data[index] = parseInt(rgbValues[0]);
      data[index + 1] = parseInt(rgbValues[1]);
      data[index + 2] = parseInt(rgbValues[2]);
      data[index + 3] = 255; // Alpha (255 bedeutet vollständig undurchsichtig)
    }
  }
  newContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  context.drawImage(newCanvas, newCanvasX, newCanvasY);
  hideLoadingOverlay();
}
```

Comment: We have a lot of relevant meta questions on the topic already, I can definitely recommend thoroughly reading the FAQs [What is the appropriate length of a Code Review question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/60) and [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) at least. Alternative platforms is something we will not recommend on. If you have additional questions after reading the linked posts, please update your meta post. It has been done before, but with varying degrees of success.

Comment: Your code itself is not the issue. The real question is what you want to get out of a review. What are your concerns with the code (reviews could look differently when you ask for maximum performance versus when looking for maximum flexibility, modularity, readability or maintainability by a third party). How much are you willing to tell us, in the questions you have in mind, about what the code does and how it does so? I've seen people successfully post massive questions here with good replies. They are not guaranteed and not guaranteed to be by a professional though.

Comment: As an aside, I noticed your comments are in German. While we have no rule against this and we prefer seeing code as-is, it can negatively affect your chances for an answer.

Comment: Is it technically possible? Yes, as long as the question fits. Whether we can do what you want from us though, is something I can only answer after your careful consideration on the above.

Comment: I'm not saying you are, but, some people are simply looking for alternative implementations. That's not what we do. [Code Review answers require an explanation](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/855), code-only answers are discouraged. We try to teach.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to upload an entire HTML/CSS code project on this site for review, rather than just a small code snippet?

[Websites are on-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/215) but your entire post must fit within ~65535 characters.

> is there another platform where I can share a whole project and receive feedback?

You'd have to look for such a place.

> Or is it possible to connect with someone privately to discuss about it further?

We do not facilitate such actions.